# Emulator page stops on Google page when used in ِAndroid Studio or VS code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

After 300 seconds the page of google converts to black
[like this pic] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EEKC.png)

I tried downloading another emulator and it didn't work.

Finally, I used the external emulator and it did not work for me ..

I wonder if the problem could be from a hardware device?

Comment: add version info for all your things.